# Microsoft Emotions API, RecognizeInVideoAsync c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, api, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

Im trying to use Microsft Emotions Api by using recognize in video, so i downloaded the client library and tried to use it, but when im debugging, it just step out without any exceptions, i thing it might be a thread prbolem - it happens in the method: "recognizeInVideoAsync".

my code:

```
public static async void testEmotionApi()
{
    var emotionServiceClient = new EmotionServiceClient("c580db97556e405980212f3ff31ac762");

    VideoEmotionRecognitionOperation videoOperation;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Downloads\testForApp.mp4", FileMode.Open))
    {
        videoOperation = await emotionServiceClient.RecognizeInVideoAsync(fs);
    }

    VideoOperationResult operationResult;
    while (true)
    {
        operationResult = await emotionServiceClient.GetOperationResultAsync(videoOperation);
        if (operationResult.Status == VideoOperationStatus.Succeeded || operationResult.Status == VideoOperationStatus.Failed)
        {
            break;
        }

        Task.Delay(30000).Wait();
    }

    var emotionRecognitionJsonString = operationResult.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `Task.Delay(30000).Wait();`? You're already `await`ing the async calls...

Comment: Why not adhere to example provided here: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/Emotion-api/documentation/GetStarted

Comment: Also not a good practice to include API keys with your sample code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the async programming works in C#.  While in source form you appear to have a single method, in practice the method is split in to multiple parts at `await` boundaries.  In other words, as you've written it, the testEmotionApi method returns after the `RecognizeInVideoAsync` is called.  The remainder of the method will be executed when the async call completes, but you've no way to wait on that result.  What you could do instead is:

```
public static async Task<VideoOperationResult> testEmotionApi()
{
    // everything here the same, except...
    return operationResult;
}

public async Task callEmotionTestApi()
{
    VideoOperationResult result = await testEmotionApi();
    ...
}
```

or, if you don't want the caller to be async,

```
public void callEmotionTestApi()
{
   VideoOperationResult result = testEmotionApi().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   ...
}
```